# How can I select values with 0 as prefix e.g. 00-09

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

My column called 'abstract' `varchar(2)` `utf8_general_ci` has the following mixed values:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ... 98, 99,
00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09,
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, ... X, Y, Z
```

How can I exclude the values `0-99` and `A-Z` in an select query without explicit nomination. I do only need the values `00-09`. I tried the following query:

`select * from table where abstract REGEXP '[^0-99]' and abstract REGEXP '[^A-Z]';`

But the `REGEXP '[^0-99]'` removes also the `00-09` from result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the easiest way is `abstract rlike '0[0-9]'`.  I don't like malicious downvoters so I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: what comes after this sequence `00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09,` it's 10, 11, 12 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
  select * from table where abstract like "0%" and abstract != "0";
```

Comment: I have done an update in my question. Please adapt your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table where abstract like %'00-0'%;
```

Comment: he only wants rows with 00-09 values. I would take a statement with like and tweak it around.

Comment: I have done an update in my question. Please adapt your answer.

Comment: did you try saurabh's answer? It should work, except you will also get values like 009 if you have those. I am only guessing here, but maybe this: select * from tables where len(select abstract from table where abstract like "0%" and abstract !="0") == 2;